# My first C# WPF ValidationRule is not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying learn how to implement data validation but my first attempt is not firing the lblSource_Error event; does anyone know what I have missed?

My Window's XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="cCompleteWPFResourcesExamples.wValidationRule"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cCompleteWPFResourcesExamples"
    Title="wValidationRule" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Customer x:Key="rCustomer" Forename="InXaml" Surname="Created" ID="1"     
AmountOutstanding="0"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel x:Name="stkMain" DataContext="{StaticResource rCustomer}">
    <Label x:Name="lblSource" Validation.Error="lblSource_Error">
        <Label.Content>
            <Binding Path="ID" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:cIDValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
    <Label x:Name="lblErrorMessage" Content="No Error Yet"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My Window's code:

```
   namespace cCompleteWPFResourcesExamples
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for wValidationRule.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class wValidationRule : Window
    {
        Customer cus = new Customer();

        public wValidationRule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cus.ID = 0;
            stkMain.DataContext = cus;
        }


        private void lblSource_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Content = e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString();
        }
    }
    }
```

My ValidationRule:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace cCompleteWPFResourcesExamples 
{
public class cIDValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int iValue = (int)value;
        if (iValue == 0) return new ValidationResult(false, "No ID number");

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
}
```

The Customer object is very simple: Just a few properties.

Thanks!

James

Comment: Label?  Labels aren't inputs, so I wouldn't think validation would work for them...

Comment: The id field of your custom object can be edited on the form or is just showed? The validation rule will be checked when you modify the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awww such a sad title :) :) First wpf validationrule is not doing what you want.

The binding engine checks each ValidationRule associated with a binding each time an input value (the binding target property value) is transferred to the binding source property.

Remember this:

You type something and the value is being persisted to the source => ValidationRule will fire.

You want to show something in Label and the value is being transmitted from source to Label => ValidationRule will never fire.

If you wish your example to work then take a TextBox instead and set the Binding Mode to TwoWay so you may type in something and Binding will persist the typed value to the source causing ValidationRule to fire. :)

Comment: Thanks: both answers are great but I used this to get me most of the way there (because it was first!): Change labels to textboxes, set binding mode=twoway but I also needed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the Customer class, and in cIDValidationRule unbox value to string then int.

Comment: @jamespearce you don't need to change the labels to textboxes. see my update

Comment: Correct. You got it :) Simplest way to demo how it works it to use TextBox and type something funny inside hehehehe

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to get it working for me, which I got from [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx)

```
<Binding Path="ID" 
NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
ValidatesOnDataErrors="true" 
ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
```

hope this helps, also watch out as the `object` that gets passed through to validation was a `string` in my case not an `int`

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    if (value is int)
    {
        int iValue = (int)value;
        if (iValue == 0) 
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "No ID number");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
    else if (value is string)
    { 
        string strValue = (string)value;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue) || strValue == "0")
        { 
            return new ValidationResult(false, "No ID number"); 
        }
    }

    return new ValidationResult(true, null);
}
```

*** Update ****

I forgot I also had to add this in for it to trigger

```
public wValidationRule()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cus.ID = 0;
    stkMain.DataContext = cus;

    //trigger the validation.
    lblSource.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```